# Array[position] returning NaN when it should be returning a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

**The Problem:**
You are going to be given a word. Your job is to return the middle character of the word. If the word's length is odd, return the middle character. If the word's length is even, return the middle 2 characters.

**My Solution**

```js
function isOdd(num) {
  return num % 2;
}

function getMiddle(str) {
  const middleDigit = (str.length + 1) / 2;
  if (isOdd(middleDigit) === 1) {
    return str[middleDigit];
  } else {
    return str[middleDigit - 0.5] + str[middleDigit + 0.5];
  }
}
console.log(getMiddle(`the`));
```

But i'm receiving a `NaN` output, rather than `h` , where has str[input] deviated from the my intention?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your execution was a little bit off!

- I changed your isOdd function to return a boolean value, instead of a number.
- After every calculation of the middle digit I subtracted 1 from the result, as we are working with indexes (and they start the count of the positions at 0, instead of 1).
- For the second middle digit when the word length is even, you just have to do "str.length/2", no need for adding or subtracting 1.

```js
    function isOdd(num) {
      return num % 2 === 1;
    }
    
    function getMiddle(str) {
      if (isOdd(str.length)) {
        return str[((str.length + 1) / 2) - 1];
      } else {
        return str[(str.length / 2) - 1] + str[str.length / 2];
      }
    }
    console.log(getMiddle(`the`));
    console.log(getMiddle(`root`));
```

Comment: I tried not to use other functions that JavaScript has like Math.floor and String slice since it seems like it's a beginner task. But Nina's answer looks a lot more cleaner and pretty!

Comment: Thanks mate you're right still don't know about those features. Tried to have a crack at it with whatever knowledge I currently have. Absolute legend

Answer (score 1):

Some annotations:

- Return a boolean for a function which starts with `is...`.
- Take the floored middle index without an offset of one.
- Check the string length instead of the middle index without having an integer value.
- Return either the single character or slice the string with adjustmens for start and end.

```js
function isOdd(num) {
  return num % 2 === 1;
}

function getMiddle(str) {
    const middleDigit = Math.floor(str.length / 2);
    return isOdd(str.length)
        ? str[middleDigit]
        : str.slice(middleDigit - 1, middleDigit + 1);
}

console.log(getMiddle('the'));
console.log(getMiddle('boot'));
```

Comment: Is the reason for the removal of the +1 because of the first element being position 0?

Comment: if you add one, you get with `str[middleDigit]` `e`, this needs another adjustment. basically if you have values in a zero based system, like indices, use the values directly and add an offset only at the last step.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the wrong value to is_odd

```
function isOdd(num) {
    return ((num % 2) === 1);
}

function getMiddle(str) {
    const middleDigit = Math.floor(str.length / 2);
    if (isOdd(str.length)) {
        return str[middleDigit];
    } else {
        return str[middleDigit - 1] + str[middleDigit];
    }
}
console.log(getMiddle(`they`));
```

Comment: This returns `ey`, so something is still off. This is fun but driving me a little bit bonkers ahha

Comment: yeah, I haven't edited the even part, edited my answer now

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

- I used **isInt()** function instead of isOdd().
- Also used **ternary operator** instead of if/else.

```
function isInt(n) {
    return n % 1 === 0;
}

function getMiddle(str) {
    const middle = (str.length / 2);
    return isInt(middle) ? str[middle - 1] : str[middle - 0.5];
}

console.log(getMiddle('the')); // h
console.log(getMiddle('abcd')); // b
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work, here was my rudimentary solution.

```js
const isEven = function (number) {
  return number % 2 === 0;
};

const getMiddle = function (inputString) {
  if (isEven(inputString.length) === true) {
    return (
      inputString[inputString.length / 2 - 1] +
      inputString[inputString.length / 2]
    );
  } else if (isEven(inputString.length) === false) {
    return inputString[inputString.length / 2 - 0.5];
  }
};
```